# Netlogo: move turtles in a planned way and visualize their paths

Tags: netlogo

I need some help here on a crucial topic in my master's thesis.

Imagine 2 types of turtles, turtle cars and houses turtles.
So the turtle cars are placed in a specific region of the world and the turtle houses are placed at random.

The main objective is for turtle cars to visit all the houses and return to the starting position.

Example of a case study:
2 cars and 5 houses

So imagine that I define the following route vector:
route: [0 2 3 1 4, 5 5 6 5 6]

in the first part are placed randomly the houses to visit, then the respective car that will make the visit, ie the car 5 visits the homes 0 2 and 1 and the car 6 visits the house 3 and 4.

I use the IDs of each turtles, depending on the total number of turtles used.
That is, using a given route vector, my cars could automatically be viewed to visit all their respective houses (in the order they are inserted into the vector, as explained above).

My question is, knowing the vector route, how do I make the car choose where to go and return to the starting point.

If someone can help me, I really appreciate it.

Comment: Thank you in advance for your response Jen.

I am beginning to study in netlog, but yes, I had already verified this command. However, I did not find an answer.
I create my world with 2 types of turtles, cars and houses (cars placed in a specific area and houses randomly). Then I get that vector from the matlab that tells me the planning of each car, in order of execution or visit.

Comment: What I do not know, is how to use the vector and apply a "route or plan" button so that the cars start visiting the houses according to vector, creating links through the houses they visit. That is, the car 5 has to know after the vector is received that it has to visit the house 0 2 and 1 ...

Comment: The way your question is worded, it seems the problem is that you don't know how to draw the paths that the turtles follow. But from your comment, I think you don't know how to make the car choose where to go. Please clarify what the problem is.

Comment: Actually the first comment implied that I would not know how to draw the paths, I'm sorry, but my question is, how make the cars choose where to go, according to a route vector.

Comment: okay, much clearer thanks. Now try breaking it into steps and deal with one step before moving on to the next. I think your steps are something like (1) create a route for each car from the combined route vector (2) make car follow route. For (2), see https://stackoverflow.com/questions/47521102/turtles-patches-and-their-moving-sequentially-from-one-patch-to-the-next/47522261#47522261

Comment: To deal with the first step - converting your route vector into routes for each car, there are some basic questions. (1) How is this being imported and where is it stored? (2) do you have a preset length? (3) Is the format definitely spaced house numbers, then a comma, then spaced car identifiers? (4) do you mean `who` for the car identifier, or do you have a variable for the identifier? That's off the top of my head. You need to do some work to get this into a form where you are asking for coding advice. Also, it may be easier to create the file of car-route pairings first, then import.

Comment: Thanks again for the response and help. I still have some doubts, as I have the combined vector and I have to separate in routes for each car. Step 1: I choose the number of cars and houses and send them to matlab to get the route. step 2: the route is imported into the netlog and stored in a variable that I define (from matlab) step 3: the length is not predefined, it depends on the number of cars and houses I select. step 4: the format is spaced but does not contain commas between the houses and the car identifiers (in the example of the question I put but as a rule the vector is only spaced

Comment: step 5: i use who to identify the car, i have no variable. I do not know now obtain instead of a combined vector, will not be a best routes vector for each car. my idea is to create something, that even changing the population of cars and houses, allow to get the routes and automatically visualize them in netlogo

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Here is some code to take an input route-vector and create a route for each car. The pairing of the car and house is taken from [NetLogo: How to filter a list using a criterion which refers on a corresponding list?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/42877203/netlogo-how-to-filter-a-list-using-a-criterion-which-refers-on-a-corresponding). This is the form with the clearest interpretation, if you can construct the `filter` version from that answer, it would be more elegant.

```
globals [ route-vector ]
breed [cars car]
cars-own [ route ]

to setup
  clear-all
  set route-vector [ 5 10 15 20 25 0 1 2 0 1 ]
  create-turtles 3 [ setxy random-xcor random-ycor ]
  make-routes
  reset-ticks
end

to make-routes
  let houses sublist route-vector 0 (length route-vector / 2 )
  let carlist sublist route-vector (length route-vector / 2 ) (length route-vector)
  ask cars [ set route [] ]
  (foreach carlist houses
    [ [the-car the-house] ->
      ask cars with [who = the-car] [ set route lput the-house route ]
    ]
  )
end
```

Please ask a separate question about using the route variable to actually move along the path. But make an attempt to do it yourself so you can show your code and describe what needs to be fixed.

Comment: Thanks for the help, I was able to adapt and I already have the route for each car.
However I tried to use the variable route for each car and make them move to their houses and I could not ... I put a separate question.